# Use asp.net routing on top of old asp system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm experimenting with using MVC routing as a temporary fix to get SEO friendly urls on an old (VB6/ASP classic) system while it's being re-written (which will take a long time).

The old system has 1 asp file with a vb6 dll that generates html which is served by a response.write in the master.asp.

so urls on that system look like this:
*www.foo.com/master.asp?sessionid=abc123&pagetype=Item&ItemID=My-widget*

I'm wondering if I can use an MVC project to create a route for cleaner urls 
and have a controller map the values and build the corresponding old url and then do a Server.Transfer to it.

So the new url would look like:
*www.foo.com/Item/My-widget*

and map to the old url at
*www.foo.com/master.asp?sessionid=abc123&pagetype=Item&ItemID=My-widget*

both could then be used interchangeably so the existing site doesn;t have to change, but I could use the new cleaner url on external sites for better SEO

Is this possible?
Is there another way to do this?

**edit:**
since it's not possible to use server.transfer from MVC, I'm now considering using routing in an ASP.net webforms app. 
This should allow me to get the routing part of the application done. Will post back here once I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use UrlRewriter.net library instead. It has a lot more features than the the built-in Routing framework (including Regex support), support for permanent redirects, and it's all configurable in the web.config file.

I've tried to use Routing before for this sort of thing but found that it became quite limiting very quickly.

http://urlrewriter.net/

Edit: you will still need a .net web project "wrapper" for your classic asp solution though, as you describe in your question, which of course comes with it's own problems as outlined in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of a way that you could do this, but you might have some luck with the url rewriter module in iis: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0):

I think this *could* be made to work, but it doesn't sound ideal.  I suspect you'd run into some issues with sharing data between the two sessions too.  It may be a good idea IF you are planning to migrate to .net, and the app will be running in a "half and half" state for a while (if so I'd suggest introducing a managed core library shared between both sides before worrying about url rewrites).

I haven't done much work with classic ASP lately, but I think this post on [URL Rewriting in Classic ASP](http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=16&p=30951) might be helpful to you.